# How to emulate C# 6 null-conditional in C# < 6

Tags: c#, c#-5.0, c#-6.0

With C# 6.0 I can do this

```
var isEqual = x.Id == y.Id
              && x.UpdatedAt == y.UpdatedAt
              && x.Name == y.Name                        
              && x.RulesUrl == y.RulesUrl
              && x.OngoingChallenges?.Count == y.OngoingChallenges?.Count
              && x.MembershipIds?.Count == y.MembershipIds?.Count;
```

Is there any nice solution to do this with C# < 6.0?

I mean this part

```
&& x.OngoingChallenges?.Count == y.OngoingChallenges?.Count
&& x.MembershipIds?.Count == y.MembershipIds?.Count;
```

Because in old projects we do not have possibility to use C# 6.0. How to write `isEqual` efficiently?

Comment: what is your solution then?

Comment: @senzacionale, for example ternary operator like: `(x.MembershipIds == null? (int?)null : x.MembershipIds.Count)`

Comment: "Because in old projects we do not have possibility to use C# 6.0". Why not?

Comment: If you have Visual Studio 2015 you can target older .NET runtimes but still use the new C# 6 compiler and syntax. The compiled IL code does not differ from the more verbose older syntax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`x.OnGoingChallenges?.Count` is equivalent to `x.OnGoingChallenges != null ? x.OnGoingChallenges.Count : default(int?)` (there're other approaches, but at the end of the day is a shortcut to null checking called *null-conditional operator*).

That is, your code can't be rewritten with a *syntatically elegant statement* without C# 6, but you can emulate this new C# 6 feature using extension methods...

```
public static class StructExtensions
{
    // Check that TProperty is nullable for the return value (this is how C#6's
    // null-conditional operator works with value types
    public static TProperty? GetOrDefault<TObject, TProperty>(this TObject someObject, Func<TObject, TProperty> propertySelectionFunc)
        where TObject : class 
        where TProperty : struct
    {
        Contract.Requires(propertySelectionFunc != null);

        return someObject == null ? default(TProperty?) : propertySelectionFunc(someObject);
    }
}
```

And now your code in C#5 would look as follows:

```
var isEqual = x.Id == y.Id
                          && x.UpdatedAt == y.UpdatedAt
                          && x.Name == y.Name                        
                          && x.RulesUrl == y.RulesUrl
                          && x.OngoingChallenges.GetOrDefault(c => c.Count) == y.OngoingChallenges.GetOrDefault(c => c.Count)
                          && x.MembershipIds.GetOrDefault(m => m.Count) == x.MembershipIds.GetOrDefault(m => m.Count);
```

The whole extension method would work for getting a value-typed property value or its default value. You might or might not extend the extension method class to also support getting a reference type value or null.

Comment: `someObject.Equals(default (TProperty))` doesn't look right. Aside from throwing a `NullReferenceException` if `someObject` is `null`, you should be comparing to `default (TObject)`, not `default (TProperty)`. And since you require `TObject : class`, you know `default (TObject)` is `null`, at which point you can simply write `someObject == null`.

Comment: Very good idea but I got an error: Does not contain a definition for 'OngoingChallenges' ...

Comment: @senzacionale Aside from the `GetOrDefault` definition itself being wrong, the example usage also has problems. It should be `x.OngoingChallenges.GetOrDefault(c => c.Count)`, not `x.OngoingChallenges.GetOrDefault(c => c.OnGoingChallenges.Count)`. Same for the other uses. :) That should explain the error you're seeing.

Comment: @hvd yeah, you're right about all issues. I've fixed them, thanks. I was evolving the sample while I forgot to refactor some things...

Comment: Why must TProperty be a struct? Null-conditional works on both class and struct.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez Sorry, check my update, I don't know why I removed the nullable return type. Null-conditional operator in OP case produces a result of type `int?`. This is why I restricted to `struct`. And this is why in my last paragraph I've pointed out that it wouldn't be hard to extend this approach to reference types

Answer (score 8):

In C# version < 6.0 you would use [ternary expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)

```
var isEqual = x.Id == y.Id
    && x.UpdatedAt == y.UpdatedAt
    && x.Name == y.Name                        
    && x.RulesUrl == y.RulesUrl
    && (x.OngoingChallenges == null ? 0 : x.OngoingChallenges.Count) ==
       (y.OngoingChallenges == null ? 0 : y.OngoingChallenges.Count)
    && (x.MembershipIds == null : 0 ? x.MembershipIds.Count) == 
       (y.MembershipIds == null : 0 : y.MembershipIds.Count);
```

As @Hamlet Hakobyan has pointed out, this not the semantically exact equivalent of the original C# 6.0 solution using `?.`, but you could change it to (according to @hvd):

```
int? count = x.MembershipIds == null : default(int?) ? x.MembershipIds.Count;
```

It depends whether you want to consider a missing collection and an empty collection as equal or not.

---

You could also use the [null-coalescing operator `??`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) and provide a replacement object. Assuming that your objects are lists of some kind:

```
var empty = new List<int>();
var isEqual = x.Id == y.Id
    && x.UpdatedAt == y.UpdatedAt
    && x.Name == y.Name                        
    && x.RulesUrl == y.RulesUrl
    && (x.OngoingChallenges ?? empty).Count == (y.OngoingChallenges ?? empty).Count
    && (x.MembershipIds ?? empty).Count == (y.MembershipIds ?? empty).Count;
```

Comment: Your first solution has issue. It assume that `null equal to 0` which is wrong assumption.

Comment: Reading the `OngoingChallenges` property twice may be a problem performance-wise if it constructs a new list (or whatever type it returns) each time the property is read. If it's meant to be a read-only list, but it's targeting a framework version that doesn't have `ReadOnlyCollection`, then that may be a good reason why it would return a new list each time. Your second option, with `empty`, nicely avoids that problem. (Nit-pick: you wouldn't refer to `a == b` as "you would use a binary expression", you would mention the equality operator by name. `?:` is called the conditional operator.)

Comment: @HamletHakobyan's point is a fair one too. That can easily be fixed by changing `0` to `default(int?)` / `(int?)null`.

Comment: I think that the solution with `default(int?)` or `(int?)null` best matches with the original C# 6.0 solution. But taking a missing collection and an empty collection as equal could still be acceptable, depending on the situation.

Comment: `?:` doesn't require the second and third operands to have the same type. It merely requires one type to be convertible to the other. `x.MembershipIds == null : null ? x.MembershipIds.Count` won't compile because `null` doesn't have a type to which `int` can convert, and `null` can't convert to `int`. However, `x.MembershipIds == null : default(int?) ? x.MembershipIds.Count` would compile, because the second operand has type `int?`, and the third operand of type `int` can be converted implicitly to `int?`. And the comment you attributed to me was by Hamlet Hakobyan. :)

Answer (score 2):

Before C# 6, i used something like this

```
 public static class CommonExtensions
 {
     public static TValue TryGet<TObject, TValue>(this TObject obj, Func<TObject, TValue> getter, TValue defaultValue = default(TValue))
         where TObject : class
     {
         return obj == null ? defaultValue : getter(obj);
     }

     //If objects types are equals
     public static bool KeyEquals<TObject, TValue>(this TObject a, TObject b, Func<TObject, TValue> keyGetter)
        where TObject : class
     {
         return a != null 
             && b != null 
             && EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default.Equals(keyGetter(a), keyGetter(b));
     }
 }



 var isEqual = x.Id == y.Id
               && x.UpdatedAt == y.UpdatedAt
               && x.Name == y.Name                        
               && x.RulesUrl == y.RulesUrl
               //v1
               && x.OngoingChallenges.TryGet(v => v.Count) == y.OngoingChallenges.TryGet(v => v.Count)
               //v2
               && x.MembershipIds.KeyEquals(y.MembershipIds, v => v.Count);
```